# Panton Semibold not rendering correctly at 16px font size

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, text-rendering

Here is my code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "p-s";
    src: url("/assets/fonts/Panton-SemiBold.otf");
}

body {
    font-family: "p-s";
}
```

### `font-size: 17px` looks good:

[image: 17px]

### But `font-size: 16px` doesn't look as good:

[image: 16px]

How can I fix this?

I've tested it in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Stupid question maybe, but can you explain what the problem is? What about the second image is not as good as the first? I don't see it.

Comment: The thing is that some letters look different.
Check out the bottom of the 5th letter... It's been curcumsized. The same thing happens to lots of letters on the second screenshot.

Comment: Oh, OK. I had to zoom in to see it, but yes, the baseline is crooked. Is this a public domain font? If so, where does it come from?

Comment: I tried to make it big enough :) My designer gave it to me... I don't know the origin of the font :(